# React: this.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the error this.updateCSSAnimation is not a function, but i'm unsure why as I have bound it in my constructor. I have tried this.updateCSSAnimation with and without parenthesis but neither work.

```
import React from 'react'

class ScrollBG extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.updateCSSAnimation = this.updateCSSAnimation.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  handleScroll () {
    this.scroll = window.ScrollY

    this.globe = document.querySelector('.globe')
    this.map = document.querySelector('.map')

    this.updateCSSAnimation()
  }

  updateCSSAnimation () {
    const scroll = this.scroll

    this.globe.style.bottom = 0 + 200 * (scroll / 250) + 'px'
    this.map.style.width = 68 + (scroll / 50) + 'rem'
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <section className='map'>
        <div className='globe'>
         stuff
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default ScrollBG
```

Comment: What is this.scroll?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `this` in `handleScroll` - is a reference to `document`. `document` does not have `updateCSSAnimation` function. Instead of `updateCSSAnimation` you need to bind `handleScroll` function:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling `this.updateCSSAnimation()` from `handleScroll` which is why you are facing issue.

Simply bind `this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)` inside `constructor`

hope this helps, happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of

```
 document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
```

and

```
document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
```

your handleScroll function is being called in a different context so the use of `this` inside that function is not referring to ScrollBG.

if you bind(this) to handleScroll it should work fine.

ie

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
```

Depending on your env, you might also be able to take advantage of arrow functions by doing this:

```
handleScroll = () => {
  this.scroll = window.ScrollY

  this.globe = document.querySelector('.globe')
  this.map = document.querySelector('.map')

  this.updateCSSAnimation()
}
```

Arrow functions automatically bind(this) to a function but in order to take advantage of them in classes in the way I've described above, you'll need to have [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) enabled in your build env. [Here's](https://repl.it/@ColinRyan2/javascriptContext) a simple example of context in JS with a class that has an arrow function and a regular method.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://blog.pragmatists.com/the-many-faces-of-this-in-javascript-5f8be40df52e